# When will date.parse() change century for 2-digits year?

Tags: javascript, date

According to the [compatibility notes on the Date.parse() method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Compatibility_notes), dates with a 2-digits year (for example : '10/10/18') will be treated as 21th century if the year is under 50.

For example :

```
Date.parse('10/10/18'); // Oct 10 2018
Date.parse('10/10/68'); // Oct 10 1968
```

I was wondering if that rule will change, and if it does, when ?

Disclaimer : I know ISO 8601 format is recommended.

Comment: I would assume it is dynamic and changes on the 1-1-2100 but if it it is following the google browser implementation I would assume only Google knows how they will/are doing it. -- Edit: Or 1-1-2050 possibly...

Comment: @Nope If it changes on 1-1-2100, that would mean that the date '1-1-99' would still be on 1999. That seems weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is not dictated by the ECMAScript specification, which says about [`Date.parse()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.parse):

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String
>   according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date
>   Time String Format
>   ([20.3.1.15](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall
>   back to any implementation-specific heuristics or
>   implementation-specific date formats.

So, your question is unanswerable. It's completely implementation-dependent and at the discretion of the browser vendor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess we will not know untill some browsers start to change, then.